# How do I return a key value when a specific column value is NOT present?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's a simplified example of my SALESORDERLINES table:

| ORDER | LINE | ITEM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | ITEMA |
| 100 | 2 | ITEMB |
| 100 | 3 | FEE |
| 101 | 1 | ITEMA |
| 101 | 2 | FEE |
| 102 | 1 | ITEMC |
| 102 | 2 | ITEMD |
| 102 | 3 | ITEME |
| 103 | 1 | ITEMA |
| 103 | 2 | FEE |
| 104 | 1 | ITEMB |
| 104 | 2 | ITEMC |

The key values for the table are ORDER and LINE.

The last line item of each order is *supposed to be* item "FEE", but occasionally order entry forgets to include it. I'm trying to find every instance where they failed to include the fee on the order.

So for the example data above, I would want to return order numbers 102 and 104 only.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess since you don't specify what resultset you desire. And surely there is another table that you did not include that represents "orders" - perhaps named SALESORDERS?

Assuming that, then I suggest:

```
select ord."ORDER" -- a terrible idea to use reserved words as names
  from dbo.SALESORDERS as ord 
where not exists (select * from dbo.SALESORDERLINES as ordlines 
       where ord."ORDER" = ordlines."ORDER" and ordlines.ITEM = 'FEE')
order by ...;
```

Certainly there are other ways. EXCEPT comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try - sorry I probably would have been better off using my actual field names in the example.

Comment: This worked thank you!  I had been trying to get Not Exists to work, but I was trying to work entirely from SalesOrderLines.  By connecting in the SalesOrders table, I was able to get it to work:

`SELECT ompSalesOrderID FROM SalesOrders
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SalesOrderLines WHERE ompSalesOrderID = omlSalesOrderID and omlPartID like 'SURCHARGE')
ORDER BY ompSalesOrderID`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT ORDER
FROM TableA
WHERE ORDER NOT IN (   
      SELECT ORDER
      FROM TableA
      WHERE ITEM = 'FEE'
      GROUP BY ORDER)
GROUP BY ORDER
```